# How to spy on inner function in angular jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Is there any way to spy on isMyResponse

```
 (function() {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('mymodule')
            .factory('MyInterceptor', MyInterceptor);

        MyInterceptor.$inject = [...];

        function MyInterceptor(...) {
            var self = this;
            self.isMyResponse = isMyResponse; 

            return {
                request: {},
                response: function (response) {
                     if(self.isMyResponse(response)){
                     }
                }
            };

            function isMyResponse(response){
                       ...
            }

        }

    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not structured particularly well to enable testing.  You would be much better off to add `isMyResponse` to the `MyInterceptor` prototype. This way, you could spy on the the prototype in your tests:

```
function MyInterceptor(...) { ... }
MyInterceptor.prototype.isMyResponse = function (...) {
  // the original isMyResponse method goes here
};
```

Then in the tests, you should be able to do something like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(MyInterceptor => {
  spyOn(MyInterceptor, 'isMyResponse');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my code and I'd rather avoid changing it unless I'm 100% sure it can't be tested as it is. And if within couple of days nobody on SO offers some other solution I guess it would be safe to assume such solution does not exist :)